# Limit the number of results in an entity's one-to-many relationship in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have the following object graph in core data.

[image]

The `Account` entity has a one-to-many relationship with `Transaction`. It's specified as a ordered set.

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display a list of accounts with its transaction records in a grouped tableview. When I fetch an entity, I want to fetch only the last 10 transactions.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Account")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "name", cacheName: nil)
resultsController?.delegate = self

do {
    try resultsController?.performFetch()
} catch {
    print("Failed to create NSFetchedResultsController: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Since the `NSFetchRequest` is for fetching `Account` objects, it's `fetchLimit` cannot be used to limit the transactions.

How do I limit the number of objects in a relationship?

Comment: You can't: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32446217/1187415.

Comment: One solution is to fetch transactions instead using a NSPredicate for the account

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603832/limit-nsfetchedresultscontroller-results-and-get-more

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this with a `NSFetchRequest` and neither with the `NSFetchedResultsController` but a workaround is to add a computed property on Account that returns the 10 latest transactions.

```
var sortedTransactions: [Transaction] {
    Array(transactions
        .sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\Transaction.date, order: .reverse))
        .prefix(10))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

You can add a computed property to your `Account` model to represent the count of the latest transactions:

```
@objc(Account)
public class Account: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var transactions: Set<Transaction>?

    var latestTransactions: [Transactions] {
        guard let transactions else { return [] }
        return Array(transactions
            .sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date })
            .prefix(10))
    }
}
```

Another way to accomplish this is by making multiple fetch requests to retrieve transactions:

1. Load all the objects ids associated with accounts:

```
let idsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObjectID>(entityName: "Account")
idsFetchRequest.resultType = .managedObjectIDResultType
let ids = try! context.fetch(idsFetchRequest.resultType)
```

2. Fetch 10 latest transactions for each account using a fetch request:

```
for id in ids {
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "account == %@", id)
            
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Transaction>(entityName: "Transaction")
   let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
            
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
   fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
   fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            
   // Retrieve the 10 most recent transactions for the associated account
   let transactions = try! container.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
}
```

If you need an account object, you can retrieve it from a transaction object.